# Error: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Please i am new in angularjs. I was trying to get data from my local machine to be populated on a page. So i got the above error. Below is my code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
table, th , td  {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 5px;
}
table tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
table tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
</style>
<script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl"> 

<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="x in names">
    <td>{{ x.id }}</td>
    <td>{{ x.menu_items }}</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
   $http.get("http://localhost:8383/database/remote.php")
   .success(function (response) {$scope.names = response.records;});
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Please, kindly help out. Many thanks

Comment: Your response JSON is invalid. Run it thru JSLint.

Comment: Thanks, tymejv. But my remote.php file returned this when i echo it out: {"records":[{"ID":"1","ITEM":"Home"},{"ID":"2","ITEM":"About_us"}]}

Comment: Works without error with your code and data: http://plnkr.co/edit/zZjJVP73EYWXPCW8ZRaU?p=preview. Of course, the table is rendered blank since in your expressions you are accessing `.id` and `.menu_items` properties, whereas your data has `.ID` and `.ITEM`

Comment: Thanks New Dev.I changed the properties but it is still giving same error.

Comment: Also i would like to say my data reside in a wamp server. Can this cause the problem?